# How do I print the elements of a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have to convert a decimal value into a string that shows the binary value, e.g. given 8, I need to print a string "1000". I have the conversion from decimal to binary, but when I print the values directly form the char array, I get little question marks instead of numbers. I know it has something to do with the way char arrays read values, but I can't figure out how to correct the issue.

```
void dec2Bin(int value, char binaryString[]) {

int remainder = 0;
int binDigit = 0;
int i = 0;
while (value != 0) {
    binDigit = value % 2;
    value /= 2;
    binaryString[i] = char(binDigit);
    i++;
}

for (int k = i - 1; k > 0; k--) {
    cout << binaryString[k];
}
}




int main()
{
cout << "Enter a decimal number: ";
int num;
cin >> num;

char binaryString[20] = "";

dec2Bin(num, binaryString);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
binaryString[i] = char(binDigit);
```

you are assigning the decimal value `0` or `1` to `binaryString[i]`. That's okay, a `char` is basically nothing more than a small integer.

The problems comes when you want to print the value, as the only overloaded `<<` operator to handle `char` treats the characters *as* a character, and in most encodings the values `0` and `1` are not printable.

There are two solutions:

1. Either you convert the character you want to print into a larger integer which won't be treated as a character:

   ```
   cout << static_cast<int>(binaryString[k]);
   ```
2. Or you make the array contain actual printable characters instead:

   ```
   binaryString[i] = binDigit + '0';
   ```

Comment: thank you so much you kind stranger. I have been trying to understand the issue for hours. I used binDigit + 0 and it works flawlessly.